# Magento 2.2 with PHP 5.4

Tags: php, magento

I got this job, and they use Magento 2, and I noticed that it can only run with php 7 and up. What is weird is that it runs on the company's server, but when I try to run (in Magento's bin directory) this command:

```
php magento --version
```

I get the message that it cannot run on PHP 5.4, and everything tells me the server is running PHP 5.4. I downloaded the Magento 2 website, and there is no alteration. It won't run in my localhost unless I switch to PHP 7.

But how is it running online? The directory is /var/www/vhosts, and /var/www/html is empty. What did the previous programmer do to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: the previous programmer installed the Magento website using Plesk. The latter allows you to choose which version of PHP you want to run.

In order to run something like (magento-root)/bin/php magento --version, for example, I had to replace php with the Plesk version, which was here:

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php
```

The default version of PHP on this server is 5.4, but Plesk is using its own version.